# What is the difference between cloud foundry droplet and warden container?

Tags: cloud, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

What is the difference between cloud foundry droplet and warden container? Is droplet just a .zip package with all needed to be executed and installed in the warden container? From what I know is a output of the staging process, but where is the point when the app is actually up and running? I would appreciate vizualized lifecycle of DAE and staging.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When a new application or a new version of an application is pushed to Cloud Foundry, the Cloud Controller selects a DEA (Droplet Execution Agent) from the pool of available DEAs to stage the application. The DEA uses the appropriate buildpack to stage the application. The result of this process is a droplet, that is an archive within Cloud Foundry that contains the application ready to run on a DEA. Once the droplet is ready, it will need hosting in a suitable environment. In Cloud Foundry, this is called a Warden container. 
[Warden](https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/features/cloud-foundry-container-technology-a-garden-overview) provides a service for managing a collection of containers and defines a protocol for clients to send requests to and receive responses from the server. Each DEA host in a Cloud Foundry deployment runs the Warden service, which manages cgroups, namespaces, process life cycle, and provides telemetry about the state of the host and each container.

[Here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/how-applications-are-staged.html) you can find a sequence diagram representing the application staging process.

So basically an application instance consists of a droplet and a Warden container. A DEA will continually broadcast the application instance health status to the health manager, which communicates internally to the Cloud Controller. Requests are directed to the DEA through the Cloud Controller.

Comment: Good explanation by Umberto. The docs are a bit behind, but DEA is in the process of being replaced by Diego (https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/diego/diego-architecture.html), and Warden is being replaced by Garden (https://blog.pivotal.io/pivotal-cloud-foundry/features/cloud-foundry-container-technology-a-garden-overview).